# Comparing MySQL DB object with a String in Java

Tags: java, mysql, boolean

I'm working on a program to manage students in a DB, and I'm working on the part where students can sign in, but for some reason I can never get the if statement to be true. I'm thinking it has something to do with the value I'm getting from the database being an object as opposed to a String. I've tried casting it to String but I get an error, is there anyway I can compare these two values? My code is below so you can take a look. I know there are other questions like this, but I've not been able to get any of their solutions to work. Thanks so much in advance.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //int i;
        //String name;

        if(e.getSource()==logInButton)
        {
            String name="";
            String password="";

            name=inputField.getText();
            password=inputField2.getText();




            try {
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, username, pass);
                PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM students");
                data = statement.executeQuery();
                while(data.next()){
                    //login = data.getObject("student_id").equals(name) && data.getObject("password").equals(password);
                    if(data.getObject("student_id").equals(name) && data.getObject("password").equals(password))
                    {
                        System.out.println("login = true");
                        logInPanel.setVisible(false);
                        postLogInPanel.setVisible(true);
                    }

                }
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing:

```
data.getObject("student_id");
```

Try:

```
data.getString("student_id");
```

This is assuming your student_id field is some sort of char field.  Also you may want to try comparing using

```
.equalsIgnoreCase //instead of .equals for username unless it is case sensitive...
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to query the database like

```
 SELECT * FROM students where username='THE ENTER USERNAME' and password='Entered password'
```

if the size of  the result set == 1 then login else invalid credentials or user doesn't exit...

Data of the object can be got via 
data.getInt("student_id"); ..

Comment: Mark it correct if it answers your question so that others can refer to it directly :)